# Mac OS High Sierra kext signing

Tags: macos, kernel-extension, macos-high-sierra

Apple recently introduced a new security feature in Mac OS High Sierra for '[User Approved Kernel Extension Loading](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2459/_index.html)'.

"*...a new feature that requires user approval before loading newly-installed third-party kernel extensions (KEXTs). When a request is made to load a KEXT that the user has not yet approved, the load request is denied. Apps or installers that treat a KEXT load failure as a hard error will need to be changed to handle this new case.*"

Does this mean developers can sign kexts with their own developer certificates, and no longer need specific Apple approved certificates to ship kexts to users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heard back from Apple that this does not change the kext code signing process, you still need certificates from them to sign your kext.

Answer (score 1):

> https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2459/_index.html

Secure Kernel Extension Loading is a new security feature of macOS High Sierra. macOS now requires you to manually approve the installation of third party kernel extensions. Everything remains the same at developer side to sign kext with apple approved certificate.

Comment: interesting, last sentence in documentation:
```
To reiterate, all third-party KEXTs that were already installed at the time of upgrading to macOS High Sierra are automatically approved and don't require any user action.
```
How exactly?